# EPUB 3.0 <dc:identifier>

Tags: epub, privacy, metadata, opf

My question is on the `<dc:identifier>`. Is the `<dc:indentifier>` unique and hashed to an IP address or MAC address?

Answer (score 7):

The dc:identifier is commonly an ISBN, though any sort of [URN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_name) will do. Further information about using  in epub can be found on the [IDPF's site](http://www.idpf.org/epub/30/spec/epub30-publications.html#sec-opf-dcidentifier), but as a quick example, you could use something like:

```
<dc:identifier id="isbn">urn:isbn:0451450523</dc:identifier>
```

As long as the identifier is unique, it should be fine. At the above link, the IDPF says:

> Every metadata section must include at least one identifier element
>   containing an unambiguous identifier for the Publication. Multiple
>   identifier elements are permitted, but only one can be marked as the
>   Unique Identifier via the package element unique-identifier attribute.

Comment: Because of the cost involved, only those EPUB 3.0 publications that are commercially published can be expected to use an ISBN as primary ID. So although these can, and will exist, they are not common, and will be a tiny minority of all EPUB 3.0 publications.
I have a 5000+ EPUB 3.0 files and none of them have an ISBN and all have a UUID as primary ID.

Comment: @Anthon, bear in mind that cost depends to a certain extent on where you are. For example, ISBNs are free in Canada, apparently.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it should be unique, and no, it is not hased to an IP or MAC address.

The example in the [EPUB 3.0 specification](http://www.idpf.org/epub/30/spec/epub30-publications.html#sec-opf-metadata-identifiers-pid) uses a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).
The particular UUID used in the example is:

```
A1B0D67E-2E81-4DF5-9E67-A64CBE366809
```

And the `4` in the position directly after the second `-` indicates that it is a [random UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29). The UUID linked to a MAC address is version 1.

There is however, no necessity that this is a UUID. The only premise is that

> a primary identifier that is unique to one and only one particular EPUB Publication

E.g. the [epub 3 examples](https://code.google.com/p/epub-samples/downloads/list) mostly use a URN, and AFAIK none of those use an ISBN.